# Converting Plain Text from UITextView into HTML Format

Tags: html, ios, uitextview

I have an iOS app that is communicating with a server via RestKit.  I am working on a posting function where a user can upload text to the server.  Given that a webpage utilizes data from the server as well it has been decided that text uploaded to the server should be in HTML format.

I searched around for a converter but all I can seem to find is one that goes from HTML to plain text not the other way.  So I'm working up a basic one to accomplish what I need.  I have run into one road block.  I'm not sure how to detect paragraphs in the plain text.

Here is what I currently do.

```
-(void)parseText {
    //this method is to parse the string into HTML tags
    NSString *htmlTag = @"<p class=\"pt\"data-seq=\"1\">";
    NSString *articleText = articleField.text;

    NSString *preTagArticleText = [htmlTag stringByAppendingString:articleText];
    NSString *postTagArticleText = [taggedArticleText stringByAppendingString:@"</p>"];

    NSLog(@"%@",appendedArticleText);
```

}

The log shows this is working properly if I only have one paragraph. My next step will most likely be to create a loop that detects a carriage return/new paragraph and formats the text like below.

```
<p class="pt" data-seq="1">The contents of paragraph 1</p> 
<p class="pt" data-seq="2">The contents of paragraph 2</p>
<p class="pt" data-seq="3">The contents of paragraph 3</p>
```

Could someone please show me how to detect the carriage return and implement it into my `parseText` method?

Comment: Check out `NSScanner`.  It is very useful for parsing.  You shouldn't need a tutorial, since it is simple enough to use.

Comment: @borrrden I totally space NSScanner.  I have glanced at it for something earlier in this project.  I'll check it out.

Comment: @borrrden took me about an hour to work out the bugs but NSScanner was the trick thanks for the input I'd give you the checkmark if you submitted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @borrrden pointing out `NSScanner`.  It has all the tools needed to easily do something like I was wanting too.  You can see how I made it work below.  I also used this [link](http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/nsscanner/) to get some examples.

```
-(void)parseText {
    appendedArticleText = @"";
    NSString *articleText = articleField.text;
    NSString *temp = nil;
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:articleText];
    int count = 0;

    while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
        count = count +1;
        NSString *htmlTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p class=\"pt\"data-seq=\"%d\">",count];
        [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&temp];

        NSString *taggedArticleText = [htmlTag stringByAppendingString:temp];
        NSString *formattedText = [taggedArticleText stringByAppendingString:@"</p>"];
        appendedArticleText = [appendedArticleText stringByAppendingString:formattedText];
    }

NSLog(@"%@",appendedArticleText);    

}
```